# Loop to print string backwards

Tags: c++, string

Program asks user for a series of strings (their name and an 8 letter word), prints their name, the first and last three letters of the word, and then prints their word backwards. need help with the for loop to display string backwards.

```
    #include <iostream> 

int main () { 


string FirstName; 

string LastName; 

string MiddleName; 

string Names; 

string string1; 

int len; 

int x;  

 cout << "Hello. What is your first name?" << endl; 

 cin >> FirstName; 

 cout << FirstName  << ", what is your last name?" << endl; 

 cin >> LastName; 

 cout << "And your middle name?" << endl; 

 cin >> MiddleName; 

 Names = LastName + ", " + FirstName + ", " + MiddleName; 

 cout << Names << endl; 

 cout << "Please enter a word with 8 or more characters (no spaces): " << endl; 

 cin >> string1; 

 len = string1.length(); 

   if (len < 8){
     cout << "Error. Please enter a word with 8 or more characters and no spaces: " <<    endl; 

     cin >> string1; 
 }

  else if (len >= 8){

     cout << "The word you entered has " << string1.length() << " characters."<<endl; 

 cout << "The first three characters are " << string1.substr(0,3) << endl; 

 cout << "The last three characters are " <<string1.substr(string1.length()-3,3) << endl; 

x = string1.length()-1; 

for (x = string1.length()-1; x >=0; x--){
 cout << "Your word backwards: " << string1[x]; 
}
}



return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Seems somewhat like homework, but that loop you are having problems with, consider just creating another string and not sending the same "Your word backwards:" out for every character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
cout << "Your word backwards: ";
for (x = string1.length()-1; x >=0; x--){
   cout << string1[x]; 
}
```

This way the loop will print each character in `string1` but in reverse order, and the text `"Your word backwards: "` only once.

Comment: Although this doesn't work with multi-byte characters; it works as long as you stick to ASCII or another single byte character set.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be fancy:

```
copy(string1.rbegin(), string1.rend(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple a way is to store a string in a temp array from backwards and then use this temp array to print reverse string.
For eg:- temp[j--]=str[i ++] ; in a loop. 
But be careful before this , intialise size of array 'temp' to size  of original array. in this case 'str' here.

Comment: Sorry for my way of answer. It's not properly indented as I have post it through my mobile

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer to you question but I'd one one of these:

```
std::cout << "Your word backwards: "
          << std::string(string1.rbegin(), string1.rend()) << '\n';

*std::copy(string1.rbegin(), string1.rend(),
           std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout << "Your word backwards: "))++ = '\n';

std::reverse(string1.begin(), string1.end());
std::cout << "Your word backwards: " << string1 << '\n';
```

Comment: You forgot: `std::cout << std::string(string1.rbegin(), string1.rend());`